# Create Foreign Key in SQL from Jupyter Lab

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to create an easy database for my project. I use SQL connector to connect and inject datas from Jupyter Lab to My SQLWorkBench.
Simple tables with Primary key are created without problems but my last table that has Foreign Keys does not work.

Below de code and the error.

```
conn.execute(sql_query) 
sql_query = CREATE TABLE away_team(
               id_team_away  INT NOT NULL,
               away_team_name  VARCHAR(45),
               PRIMARY KEY (id_team_away)
               )
conn.execute(sql_query)
df_away_team.to_sql('away_team',conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=True)


df_home_team = df[[ 'home_team']]
sql_query = ''' DROP TABLE IF EXISTS home_team
conn.execute(sql_query)
sql_query = '''CREATE TABLE home_team(
   id_home_team  INT NOT NULL,
   home_team_name  VARCHAR(45),
     
   PRIMARY KEY (id_home_team)
   )
'''
conn.execute(sql_query)
df_home_team.to_sql('home_team',conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=True)


dftournament = df[[ 'tournament']]
sql_query = ''' DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tournaments'''
conn.execute(sql_query)
sql_query = '''CREATE TABLE tournaments(
   id_tournaments  INT NOT NULL,
   tournament  INT(100),
  
   PRIMARY KEY (id_tournaments)
   )
'''
conn.execute(sql_query)
dftournament.to_sql('tournaments',conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=True)


sql_query = ''' DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  results'''
conn.execute(sql_query)
sql_query = '''CREATE TABLE results(
   id_results  INT NOT NULL,
   home_team_fifa_rank BIGINT,
   home_team_goalkeeper_score DOUBLE,
   home_team_mean_offense_score DOUBLE, 
   home_team_mean_midfield_score DOUBLE,
   away_team_fifa_rank BIGINT,
   away_team_goalkeeper_score DOUBLE,
   away_team_mean_defense_score DOUBLE,
   away_team_mean_midfield_score DOUBLE,
   shoot_out BIGINT,
   date DATETIME,
   result INT,
   home_team_id  INT NOT NULL,
   away_team_id  INT NOT NULL,
   tournaments_id  INT NOT NULL,
     
   PRIMARY KEY (id_results),
   FOREIGN KEY (away_team_id) REFERENCES away_team (id_away_team),
   FOREIGN KEY (home_team_id) REFERENCES home_team (id_home_team),
   FOREIGN KEY (tournaments_id) REFERENCES tournaments (id_tournaments)
   )
'''
conn.execute(sql_query)

dfresult.to_sql('results',conn, if_exists = 'replace', index=True)

# DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError) 3734 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'id_away_team' for constraint 'results_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'away_team' `
```

Comment: Your primary key is `id_team_away`, but your foreign key references `id_away_team`.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not seem to fix the problem; I have changed as you said and still thiis error appears. ' 3734 (HY000): Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing column 'id_team_away' for constraint 'results_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'away_team' '